# Bootstrap date range picker mobile highlights previous date when changing date

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I use bootstrap [date range picker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) with 2 calendars so people can select `start` and `end` dates. Something new I have done is, once a user select the START date, i focus on the END date so the calendar automatically pops up.

**FIDDLE?**

I tried to setup a fiddle but it just doesnt work on a fiddle, but you can always test on the plugin website as it happends on the original plugin as well. See [date range picker website](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) here.

**THE PROBLEM**

On iPhone, when I select the start date the enddate calendar automatically pops up, which is great. But the problem is, it hangs onto a hover where I had my finger. So if you look at the screenshot, I selected `8th` on the START calendar and when it focuses onto the END calendar it hovers over `6th` as well automatically because I had my finger on the same area when I selected `8th`.

How can this be fixed? I tried all the `ios hover issue` fixing plugins and solutions out there but nothings seems to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you destroy and reinitialize end-date date-picker when you display it after user select start-date?

It will make website little slow whenever user select date.
I don't have I-phone so I can't replicate so it's just assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I would set `autoclose: true`, so that the Datepicker automatically closes when a date is selected.
Then, you can use `hide` event to know when to show 'end' Datepicker, but here you set a small timeout like 100-200ms

```
$('#datepicker-start').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
}).on( 'hide', function(e) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#datepicker-end').datepicker('show');
    }, 100)
});
$('#datepicker-end').datepicker();
```

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLu1z7vp/5/)